# Meaning of 'keep one's removed'

Tags: idioms, idiom-meaning

Does it always mean 'keep someone in distance' or there is something else?

Comment: This isn't an expression I've ever heard of - what is the source - can you share that with us?

Comment: Do you mean "keep at one remove"? See [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/at-one-remove-at-several-removes)

Comment: Can you please provide some context?

Comment: I read it on canadian forum, sorry don't remember where. It was 'I couldn't keep him removed'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you used the words

> keep one's removed'

I assume that from the original post, the phrase you are asking about is...

> *'To keep one's self removed'* from someone or something

The phrase meaning to stay away from or steer clear of someone or something; in short, to keep one's distance.

Taking the following definitions of

- Keep - *To stay in, on, or at (a place or position)*
- Removed - *Separated by distance or abstract distinction*

---

References:

1. [Keep](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/keep)
2. [Removed](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/removed)